# iOS 6 Custom Container View Controller

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom view container that use the following code to dismiss the current viewController and present the previous one...

```
- (void)popToViewControllerwithAnimation:(AnimationStyle)animation
{
    if(self.currentChildIndex == 0)
        return;

    UIViewController *currentChildController = self.childViewControllers[self.currentChildIndex];

    self.currentChildIndex--;

    UIViewController *previousChildController = self.childViewControllers[self.currentChildIndex];

    if(animation == kSlideRight || animation == kSlideDown) {

        CGRect onScreenFrame = self.view.bounds;

        CGRect offScreenFrame = self.view.bounds;

        CGFloat duration = 0.35;

        if(animation == kSlideRight) {

            offScreenFrame.origin.x += offScreenFrame.size.width;

            duration = 0.3;
        }

        if(animation == kSlideDown)
            offScreenFrame.origin.y += offScreenFrame.size.height;

        [currentChildController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

        [self addChildViewController:previousChildController];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        currentChildController.view.frame = offScreenFrame;

        previousChildController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

        previousChildController.view.frame = onScreenFrame;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            [currentChildController.view removeFromSuperview];

            [currentChildController removeFromParentViewController];

            [previousChildController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        }];

    }
}
```

All is working fine except the `previousViewController` appearance methods never get called...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add `previousChildController.view` to `self.view`.

Comment: It is added in my presentation code and I don't dispose of it.

Comment: Well, keep the instance, but remove it from the super view and add it when needed.

Comment: The transition works fine - I get back to the state I require with the exception of `viewWillAppear:` / `viewDidAppear:` being called. I moved it around and put `addSubview:` into this method and they still don't fire.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't using `removeFromSuperview, I was just adding it again - silly me. I think it is roughly working - however my animations are now all messed up - fix one thing to break the next is the order of the day.

Comment: The animation delay is 0.0 in the code snippet - checkout that. Another thing is you need to add the previous view controller's view and the fire the animation.